# 2D Laplace Equation with Dirichlet Condition

Tags: fourier-analysis

I'm having trouble following the solution for this question. Firstly (underlined in orange) why is the general solution of this form. I would have thought it would be the more general $A(w)e^{wy}+B(w)e^{-wy}$
And for the green part I don't really follow it all.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$$
\Phi\pars{x,y}=\int\tilde{\Phi}\pars{\vec{k}}\expo{\ic\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}\,{\dd^{2}\vec{k} \over \pars{2\pi}^{2}}\quad\imp\quad
\int\tilde{\Phi}\pars{\vec{k}}\pars{-k_{x}^{2} -k_{y}^{2}}
\expo{\ic\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}\,{\dd^{2}\vec{k} \over \pars{2\pi}^{2}}
=0
$$
$\ds{\imp\quad k_{y} = \pm\verts{k_{x}}\ic}$

> $$
> \Phi\pars{x,y}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm B}\pars{k_{x}}
> \exp\pars{\ic k_{x}x \color{#c00000}{\Large -} \verts{k_{x}}y}\,{\dd k_{x} \over 2\pi}
> $$

$$
{\rm p}\pars{x}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm B}\pars{k_{x}}
\exp\pars{\ic k_{x}x}\,{\dd k_{x} \over 2\pi}\quad\imp\quad
{\rm B}\pars{k_{x}} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm p}\pars{\xi}\expo{-\ic k_{x}\xi}\,\dd\xi
$$

> \begin{align}
> \color{#00f}{\large\Phi\pars{x,y}}&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bracks{%
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm p}\pars{\xi}\expo{-\ic k_{x}\xi}\,\dd\xi}
> \expo{\ic k_{x}x - \verts{k_{x}}y}\,{\dd k_{x} \over 2\pi}
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over 2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm p}\pars{\xi}
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{\ic k_{x}\pars{x - \xi} - \verts{k_{x}}y}\,\dd k_{x}
> \,\dd\xi 
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over \pi}\Re\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm p}\pars{\xi}
> \int_{0}^{\infty}\!\!\!\!\!\expo{k_{x}\bracks{\ic\pars{x - \xi} - y}}\,\dd k_{x}
> \,\dd\xi
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over \pi}\Re\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm p}\pars{\xi}
> {-1 \over \ic\pars{x - \xi} - y}\,\dd\xi
> ={1 \over \pi}\Re\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm p}\pars{\xi}
> {\ic\pars{x - \xi} + y \over \pars{x - \xi}^{2} + y^{2}}\,\dd\xi
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#00f}{\large{y \over \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
> {{\rm p}\pars{\xi} \over \pars{x - \xi}^{2} + y^{2}}\,\dd\xi}
> \end{align}

Comment: Thanks, but i'm looking for something a tad more specific

Comment: @usainlightning My answer is a Fourier technique application. It's the only way to do it with Fourier. Thanks.